# Second ajax function not firing when called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two AJAX functions, one links to a file that edits a MYSQL table, and the other loads the new content to a `<div>`

The function to load the new data is not being fired.

This function links to a page called `clear_tasks.php` which `TRUNCATE`s a table in my database.

```
function clear_tasks(){

    var xmlhttp;

    if( window.XMLHttpRequest ){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' );
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'script_files/clear_tasks.php', true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

This next function links to a page called `task_info.php` which `echo`s a list of all the table entries.

```
function load_content_from_file( div_id, url ){

    var xmlhttp;

    if( window.XMLHttpRequest ){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' );
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ){
            document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

The `<div>` which should trigger these events looks as follows:

```
<div onClick="clear_tasks(); load_content_from_file('task_list', 'script_files/task_info.php');">Clear Tasks</div>
```

The `load_content_from_file()` function uses two parameters: `div_id` which is the div into which the content from `task_info.php` should be loaded, and `url` which of course is the source file itself (`task_info.php`)

The `load_content_from_file()` function is not being fired and I have to refresh the page to see the new content (I use `load_content_from_file()` in a `$(document).ready()` function).

How come the `load_content_from_file()` function is not firing? Ive tried using `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` functions but to no avail.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the database insert process happening **after** the `load_content_from_file()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code on my own side. Both functions are `'fired clear_tasks()'` and `'load_content_from_file'` are firing when I click on 'Clear Tasks'.

The problem may be on your path with  `'script_files/task_info.php'`, Or inside the `task_info.php` which is supposed to response the data for 'task_list' div.

Because if I return simple text by 'task_info.php', then the text would appended into 'task_list' div smoothly.